# Explain how the functional programming model differs from the procedural or object orientated models

Tags: functional-programming

Can anyone explain how the functional programming model differs from the procedural or object orientated models.
I cannot conclude a good answer myself.

Comment: Please tell us what answer you found, we can help you to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion FP is about *pure* functions (that is functions in a mathematical sense) - which implies [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) and, if you continue the thouhgt, *immutable* data.

This is the biggest difference I see: you don't **mutate** data - and most other aspects either directly follow from this or from cool type-systems (which are not necessary for a language to be called *functional*) and the academic nature.

But of course there is far more to it and you can read [papers](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf), complete books or just [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) about it.

---

please note that you can *dispute* the **pure** property and then things get a lot more fuzzy ... which should not surprise you, as most *functional languages* in wide to allow for mutation (Clojure, Scala, F#, Ocaml, ...) and there are not many *pure* ones.

In this case the biggest difference might be the way you abstract things with higher-order-functions (at least functions should be *first class citizens* - meaning you can pass them around and have them as values).

But overall this question is really **opinionated** and will very likely be closed as *to broad* or something - maybe you should ask for details instead of the **big picture**